# why must $\int_0^\infty 5 e^{(t-5)x} dx$ be positive?

Tags: calculus

Why does the output of

$\int_0^\infty 5 e^{(t-5)x} dx$

need to be positive? I am told $t<5$ but I don't get why this is necessary in general (tho it makes sense for a PDF)

Comment: I have a feeling that you haven't asked the question you *want* to ask. Especially since the integral is rather direct to compute, and is immediately positive.

Comment: You need $t < 5$ for the improper integral to converge.

Comment: @user296602 I agree, I don't think I had words for the question I wanted sadly. Robert Israel's comment was more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $e^a > 0 $ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So here, $a = (t-5)x$, which is a real number, so $e^{(t-5)x}$ is positive. Because the function inside the integral is positive, increasing, and continuous for all real numbers, taking the integral necessarily produces a positive result.

Answer (score 1):

Because $5e^{(t-5)x}$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Since $5e^{(t-5)x}>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, the integral is guaranteed at least nonnegative, but $5e^{(t-5)x}$ is continuous and strictly greater than zero, the integral is positive.